# Is base case function mandatory or could it be automatically synthesized?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code :

```
void print()
{
    // This is our base case fn
    ;; // Do nothing
}

template <typename type1, typename... argspack>
void print(type1 a, argspack... args_rest)
{
    cout << a << ((sizeof...(args_rest) != 0) ? "," : "\n");
    print(args_rest...); // I guess this recursive call is inevitable
}
```

If the recursive call to variadic function is inevitable, the base case function is also inevitable. If so, is there a language feature, perhaps one
that comes with modern c++,  that help a programmer get away without writing a base case function?

Comment: Do you mean synthesized by the compiler?

Comment: Yes, being automatically synthesized by the compiler is what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dummy is one way. Another is to make it a single argument function that actually does work:

```
template<typename T>
void print(T a)
{
  std::cout << a;
}

template <typename type1, typename... argspack>
void print(type1 a, argspack... args_rest)
{
    print(a);
    std::cout << ((sizeof...(args_rest) != 0) ? "," : "\n");
    print(args_rest...); // I guess this recursive call is inevitable
}
```

A benefit to this approach is that it provides a customization point too. If some type wants to provide its own `print` implementation, all it has to do is write the overload. ADL will find it and overload resolution will favor it.

To be perfectly clear, you have to write the base case yourself. The language doesn't consider those two functions as related beyond being overloads of the same name. It isn't even aware there *needs* to be a base case, that is our logical requirement.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. But having read this, I should assume that there is no language construct that will provide a default implementation of a base class function, which indeed, was my original question.

Comment: @sjsam - Nope. The language doesn't consider those two functions as related, only as competing overloads.

Comment: Thanks for that added last line. Makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

Another (slightly elaborate) way which avoids recursion and a trailing comma:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct linefeed {};

template<typename...Args>
void print(Args&&... args) 
{
    const char* sep = "";
    auto print_with_sep = [&sep](auto& os, auto& arg)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same<std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>, linefeed>())
        {
            sep = "";
            os << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            os << sep << arg;
            sep = ",";
        }
    };

    auto print_all = [&](auto&&...things)
    {
        (print_with_sep(std::cout, things), ...);
    };

    print_all(args..., linefeed());
}

int main()
{
    print(1,2,3,4,5, "hello");
    print("world", 5,4,3,2,1);
}
```

expected output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,hello
world,5,4,3,2,1
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/770912eee67d04ac

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to [Fold Expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) which is supported as of C++17.

I came up with the code almost similar to your code but it has a trailing comma.

```cpp
template<typename... argspack>
void print(argspack&&... args) {
  ((cout << args << ","), ...) << "\n";
}
```

I am not sure there is a way to get exactly the same with your code using Fold Expression. Since we `sizeof...(args)` is always the initial size in this version.

Comment: Handling separator is possible, by using variable for example.

Answer (score 0):

With one function in C++11:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void print(Ts... args)
{
    const char* sep = "";
    const int dummy[] = {((std::cout << sep << args), (sep = ", "), 0)..., 0};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

dummy array trick can be replaced by fold expression in C++17:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void print(Ts... args)
{
    const char* sep = "";
    (((std::cout << sep << args), (sep = ", ")), ...);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```